# Visual studio Attaching debugger to windows service - never hits the break points

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-services

I attach VS 2010 to service process; after that I put breakpoint in several methods but they never seem to be hit. Any idea or tips?

Note: The services process installed is a release build. Do I have to have a debug build installed for this?

Comment: no; just added it in question too. Should it has to be debug build?

Comment: Yes. In release mode, debug symbols and project state info are not built, hence the debugger cannot locate the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a debug build for this.

In **release** mode, the debug info is discarded and code is optimized, so there is no way to link to original source code.

In **debug** mode, debugging and project state information is retained so the debugger canlink to the source code. It also emits `DebuggableAttribute` that tells JIT compiler that the assembly has debug info.

Helpful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx

Comment: Does it mean there is no way of debugging a service in release mode? cuz i have limited control on putting debug build on that machine.

Comment: @Silverlight Student: that is correct, you won't be able to debug unless you get a debug build for the services.

Comment: This is a widely held myth, debugging a Release build is quite possible.  Just not easy since local variables usually can't be inspected and code is re-arranged, inlined or optimized away.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Do you mean via WinDbg or similar tools?

Comment: Start a new win32 console app, switch to the Release configuration and use Debug + Step In.